# Check if phone number available

Tags: javascript, java, android, jakarta-ee, asp.net-web-api

i want to get notify when someone i call and he is  unavailable - at the first moment he became available. is there any way to check it in JAVA, Android, Javascript or some API request?

is there anyway to make 'fake phone call' and get response if number available or not?

Comment: yes, you dial *66 (in north america) and pay through the nose for "busy call return" to be activated on that number.

Comment: this is not programaticly my friend. and even not international option

Answer (score 1):

you can't fake a phone call, but this is not unpossible to do programatically. However, its not trivial and requires that you have at least two things set up at the very least

1. a service account with a voip provider, or at the very least a DID number set to route calls to your server
2. You'll need an instance of Freeswitch or Asterisk running on that server to handle the call

both Freeswtich and Asterisk have Java Libraries that you can use to hook into a running instance and issue commands.

Here is a link to the [Freeswich ESL library](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_Socket_Library) you can use that to initiate voip calls and receive information about the call.  Ideally you could initiate a call programmatically then if it goes through have it ring your IP phone to connect the call.  If the line was busy, you would just retry the call until it wasn't.  I'll leave the research on how to do it up to you, but it definitely is possible.

Here are some useful links:

- http://www.voip-info.org/
- http://www.asterisk.org/
- https://freeswitch.org/

Good luck